# Gravar um valor Dword em Decimal no Registro do Windows

Tags: vb.net

[image: SS]

Preciso gravar um registro Dword em decimal no Visual Basic Express 2013.

Como o código foi escrito:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim Dec As Decimal
    Dim Numero = 22I
    My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MinhaChaveCriada",
   "DECIMAL" & Dec, Numero, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
End Sub
```

Quando grava no registro ele está adicionando um 0 "ZERO" na frente do texto de criação que seria "DECIMAL" somente e não DECIMAL0 ele sempre coloca esse zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade você é quem está adicionando um zero na frente do texto, nesta linha:

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MinhaChaveCriada",
   "DECIMAL" & Dec, Numero, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
             ------
```

Como você define que `Dec` é decimal, mas não atribui nenhum valor, `Dec` permanece inicializado com o valor `0`.

Em seguida, você concatena (operador `&`) a string `"DECIMAL"` com `Dec`, portanto resultando em `DECIMAL0`.

Para deixar apenas `DECIMAL`, basta remover o `& Dec` do `SetValue` (e nem declarar a variável `Dec` se não pretende usar para nada):

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MinhaChaveCriada",
   "DECIMAL", Numero, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
```

Comment: Só não te dou um beijo porque é homem ; Obrigado man .

Comment: Ficou assim para quem está trabalhando com os registros .
   Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

        Dim Numero = 22I
        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MinhaChaveCriada",
       "DECIMAL", Numero, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
    End Sub